# Creating batch file from shell file

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, batch-file

I have to convert the following shell file into a batch file:

```
\#!/bin/bash
\#
\# Generates and compiles a lexer or parser and runs it (this means
\# that the lexer/parser must contain a main method)
\#
\# Example usage: antlr4-run.sh Lexer.g4

DIR="$(cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` && pwd)"
ANTLR_JAR=$DIR/lib/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar
BASENAME="${1%.*}"
OUTDIR=out

echo "Generating..."
java -jar $ANTLR_JAR $1 -o $OUTDIR || exit 1

echo "Compiling..."
(cd $OUTDIR; javac -cp .:$ANTLR_JAR ${BASENAME}*.java) || exit 1

\#\# run (try parser first, then lexer, then plain)
echo "Input (end with ^D):"

if [[ -a $OUTDIR/${BASENAME}Parser.class ]] ; then
      (cd $OUTDIR; java -cp .:$ANTLR_JAR ${BASENAME}Parser) || exit 1 
elif [[ -a $OUTDIR/${BASENAME}Lexer.class ]] ; then
      (cd $OUTDIR; java -cp .:$ANTLR_JAR ${BASENAME}Lexer) || exit 1 
elif [[ -a $OUTDIR/${BASENAME}.class ]] ; then
      (cd $OUTDIR; java -cp .:$ANTLR_JAR ${BASENAME}) || exit 1 
fi

exit 1
```

Could you please help me with give an example for the following line?

```
DIR="$(cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` && pwd)"
```

I know that I have to define a variable in a batch file with set Directory ="..." for example and that `$` is a `commandoline parameter`... but I don't know how to write this line in a batch file :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the variable name *DIR* to something else (*Win* is case insensitive, and *dir* is a command). However, here's the equivalent (check [[MS.Docs]: Batch parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call#batch-parameters) for more details):

```bat
set _DIRNAME=%~dp0
```

Note that it will not remove the trailing *backslash* ("***\***").

More: if the trailing  "***\***" is a problem, this is what can be done:

```bat
set _DIRNAME=%~dp0
set _DIRNAME=%_DIRNAME:~0,-1%
```

It is a workaround (*gainarie*), but it works.

***@EDIT0***:

Also, posting the code from (last) comment.

***@EDIT1***:

Since that method is not robust (e.g. if the extension is present elsewhere in the path, it will be stripped out as well), also posting an alternative that works and only requires one line:

*script.bat*:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _EXT=%~x1
set _NAME_EXT=%~1
set _NAME=!_NAME_EXT:%_EXT%=!

echo Name (env vars): %_NAME%

:: This does the trick, and it's waaay better in every possible way
echo Name (bat args): %~d1%~p1%~n1
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513>script.bat "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513\a.bat"
> Name (env vars): e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513\a
> Name (bat args): e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513\a
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513>script.bat "c:\dir_bat\a.bat"
> Name (env vars): c:\dir_bat\a
> Name (bat args): c:\dir_bat\a
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513>script.bat "c:\dir.bat\a.bat"
> Name (env vars): c:\dir\a
> Name (bat args): c:\dir.bat\a
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513>script.bat "c:\dir.batch\a.bat"
> Name (env vars): c:\dirch\a
> Name (bat args): c:\dir.batch\a
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513>script.bat "c:\dir.batch\a.bat1"
> Name (env vars): c:\dir.batch\a
> Name (bat args): c:\dir.batch\a
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513>script.bat "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513\ a.bat"
> Name (env vars): e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513\ a
> Name (bat args): e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029928513\ a
> ```

Comment: To also remove the trailing "\", here's what you can do:
`code`
    set DIRNAME_=%~dp0
    set DIRNAME=%DIRNAME_:~0,-1%
`code`
It is a workaround(gainarie) but it works.

Comment: thank you!  so that all i need to write for this line in the shell script? whats about the BASH_SOURCE[0]? And could you help me with the line BASENAME="${1%.*}" too?  i already looked for older posts and the common shell and batch (cmd) commands....

Comment: BASH_SOURCE[0] is the name of the script (works when the script is run **and** sourced).

Comment: Here's the code:

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set EXT=%~x1
    set SELF=%~1
    set BASENAME=!SELF:%EXT%=!